# Passing parameters in Silverlight Usercontrol

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a usercontrol called MyUserControl.xaml which dynamically adds another user control:

UserControl myControl = (UserControl)assembly.CreateInstance ("EditControlPage");
myControl.Name = "MyUserControl";

This is a shared Edit control which will be shown an several other controls aswell.

What i need is when I access the EditControlPage I know which control I am using. I tried adding the myControl.Name as above then when on the Edit page  doing var name = this.Name but it returns blank.

Comment: Ill try and explain better. I have UserControl1 which is a child of Page1. How do i find the name of Page1 when inside the code of UserControl1.

Comment: You can search through hierarchy of your controls upper until you find the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved by adding a Property in the App.xaml file of the project as this can be shared between all controls on the app

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do UserControl myControl = new EditControlPage(parameters); ?

Comment: Because the code is used to load various different user controls with differnet page names. e.g      UserControl myControl = (UserControl)assembly.CreateInstance(type.Namespace + ".WebParts." + pageControl.FileName);